# Problem with List Dimension Outer Map

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, parallelization, map

I am currently handling a big list which has the following dimension: `{6, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 8}` where the last number `8` represent a number of equation that are in each sublist. If I apply solve to the 7 level

```
Ssols = Map[Flatten[Solve[#, vars]] &,SSEquations, {7}]
```

I get a list in which

```
Dimensions[Ssols]
Dimensions[Ssols[[1]]]
```

> {1}
>   {6, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1}

so until now it seems fine, even if I don't understand this wrapping that comes out with another List containing the previous one.

But then things get compplicated

```
SCSystem = 
  Outer[# && #2 && #3 && #4 && #5 &, Eq1, Eq4, Eq5, Eq6, Eq8, {2}] 
  /.SCEq1 /. SCEq4 /. SCEq5 /. SCEq6 /. SCEq8 // MatrixForm;
Dimensions[SCSystem[[1]]]
```

> {6, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1}

where: `EqX = {IX,IIX, etc}` and `SCEqX ={IX->a+b<c,etc.}` or similar inequalities

Now if I apply a `FullSimplify` to get which one of this set of inequalities is `True` and which one is not, and also geting a simplified form of the set of inequalities

```
 SCsols = ParallelMap[FullSimplify[#] &, SCSystem, {7}] //MatrixForm
```

I get something really strange

```
Dimensions[SCsols[[1]]]
Dimensions[SCsols[[1, 1]]]
```

> {1}
>   {6, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1}

How this is possible? Do you have any suggestions?
And moreover I would like to go and substitute for each level 6 of `Ssols` the corresponding value in `SCsols` and I thought to do in the following way:

```
SCsolsSub = 
  Parallelize[Outer[#1 /. #2 &, SCsols, Ssols],{6}] // MatrixForm
```

but doesn't work probalby because the two list have not the same dimensions.

Comment: First: Remove `//MatrixForm` at the end of your expressions. If you want to visualize your equations as matrices do something like: `mat={{0,0},{1,1}}; mat//MatrixForm`.

Comment: Hi, yes i just figured out that matrixform change the size of the list it take in input...i've removed it and now is going fine with the dimension, i'm not looking at the last operation.
thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: Then, if you need further help you should provide a _small_ working example or, if it's not possible, `vars`, `SSEquations` and every unknown in your post.

Comment: Uhm..it's kind of hard for me to report data and probably due to the big amount of variable will make everything more messy...what i'm trying to solve is actually find a function (or write one) that given to list with several levels. One containin expression of variable and one containing the substituition rules. I want that in the first one i substitute the second.

A={{a+b<c&&a+c>2},{a+b>c&&a+c>5}}
B={{a->1,b->2,c->3},{a->1,b->5,c->4}}

and then get

f[A/.B]
C ={{1+2<3&&1+3>2},{1+5>4&&1+4>5}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after removing the //MatrixForm, all the dimension were in agreement,
in order to solve the last problem i've used:

> SCsolsSub = MapThread[Reduce[#1 /. #2] &, {SCsols, SSsols}, 6]